# How to associate keyboard shortcut with respect to IntelliJ IDE for running Groovy scripts?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I want to run groovy script in IDE Scripting Console through keyboard shortcut . Help me with it .

Comment: This question is more about your IDE than about groovy. Please add tags related to Intellij

Comment: You may use shortcut for "Run -> Run 'file_name'" action.